# Selenium find flex element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get element text with selenium.

this is the link "https://rasm.io/company/10101802743/Direct/"

and I want to get this flex element by XPATH :

/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div

but this error appears:

no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: That link can't be opened...

Comment: Please, send an screenshot about the element you want to take. With the xpath you shared there is no element.